# Alarm clock code: mContext variable cant be resolved

Tags: android

I am trying to build the alarmclock source code after copy pasting in my files
While compilation, I get the error, mContext cannot be resolved.
Here is the link to this piece of code: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/packages/apps/AlarmClock/src/com/android/alarmclock/DigitalClock.java

And I have copy pasted some part of the code which uses mContext below

```
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (Log.LOGV) Log.v("onAttachedToWindow " + this);

    if (mAttached) return;
    mAttached = true;

    if (mAnimate) {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animate_circle);
        /* Start the animation (looped playback by default). */
        ((AnimationDrawable) getBackground()).start();
    }

    if (mLive) {
        /* monitor time ticks, time changed, timezone */
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        mContext.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);

    }

    /* monitor 12/24-hour display preference */
    mFormatChangeObserver = new FormatChangeObserver();

    mContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(

            Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mFormatChangeObserver); 

    updateTime();
}

private void setDateFormat() {      

    mFormat = Alarms.get24HourMode(mContext) ? Alarms.M24 : M12;
    mAmPm.setShowAmPm(mFormat == M12);
}
```

To solve this compilation error, I put this statement in my code

```
Context mContext;
```

But though the compilation errors are solved, on launch in the emulator, the application throws an exception and exits without launching.

Can some one please tell me how to use this context thing or wat shud i write as an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You need to initiate mContext. There are some different ways to do this. In the activity you could do:

```
Context mContext = this;
```

or generally:

```
Context mContext = getContext();
```

Comment: Then please except the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mContext, use the getContext() method to get hold of a context. The sample code there perhaps missed this part.

Comment: can you please paste the piece of code to be written? I am new to android :(

Comment: Look at Heinrisch's answer. The 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

instead of **mContext** use **getApplicationContext()** .Hope it Will Works

Answer (score 1):

here you need to add context of your activity try my code

```
mFormat = Alarms.get24HourMode(this) ? Alarms.M24 : M12;
        mAmPm.setShowAmPm(mFormat == M12)

;
```

need more of your code

but my suggestion is where you are getting your context in this view or activity intialize your mContext variable there and it will work