# Error in building Alarm app from android source

Tags: android, adt, android-source, android-alarms

I want to build an app which extends basic alarm clock functionality. Since I am not inventing any wheel in the alarm functionality, I would like to use the android default alarm which is available openly.

However I have tried to build it many times but there are just too many errors (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595800/android-clock-source-git-clone-import-error) also):

I tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595929/1958635) also but I am still not able to build it.

Can anyone please guide on how to build the android application provided in git android tree.

Links I referred to:

1. [Alarm clock code: mContext variable cant be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118376/alarm-clock-code-mcontext-variable-cant-be-resolved)
2. [Alarm Clock from GIT - Gives error - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201666/alarm-clock-from-git-gives-error-android)

Updates:

1.)

```
    Alarms.java: 
    Line 463: Intent alarmChanged = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED);
    Error: ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Solved this error but replacing the line with (Thanks to @shayanpourvatan ):

```
final String ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED = "android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED"; Intent alarmChanged = new Intent(ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED);
```

2.)

```
    AlarmKlaxon.java
    Line 89: mVibrator = new Vibrator();
    Error: Cannot instantiate the type Vibrator

    -----------------------------------
```

Solved by replacing the line with:

```
mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

3.)

```
SetAlarm.java
    Line 115: FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()
                .findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.content);
    Error:com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Solved by replacing :

```
 com.android.internal.R.id.content into android.R.id.content
```

Comment: for `Call requires API level 3` you need change min sdk version to 3 in manifest file, for other post more code.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan were you able to successfully build the app from android source ?

Comment: for first problem you can change your code with:

    final String ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED = "android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED";
    Intent alarmChanged = new Intent(ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved all the error and was able to compile and run on device. Need to do testing and check for deprecations. Here is how I solved them:

1.)

```
Alarms.java: 
Line 463: Intent alarmChanged = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED);
Error: ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Solved this error but replacing the line with (Thanks to @shayanpourvatan ):

```
final String ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED = "android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED"; Intent alarmChanged = new Intent(ACTION_ALARM_CHANGED);
```

2.)

```
AlarmKlaxon.java
Line 89: mVibrator = new Vibrator();
Error: Cannot instantiate the type Vibrator

-----------------------------------
```

Solved by replacing the line with:

```
mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

3.)

```
SetAlarm.java
    Line 115: FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()
                .findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.content);
    Error:com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Solved by replacing :

```
com.android.internal.R.id.content into android.R.id.content
```

And the lastly:

```
The specified child already has a parent
```

error is fixed as mentioned below:

[The specified child already has a parent in google alarmclock code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193389/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-in-google-alarmclock-code)